# Returning value of variable from ajax function

Tags: ajax

I want to get stored value in my defined variable. I have written this code:

```
 var phn=$.ajax({
url:   ipaddress+"/.../.../...",
type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(MyForm1),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    success:function(response){
        console.log(response);
        $.each(response, function(k, v) {
                rcvdResponse.push(v);
                console.log(rcvdResponse);
        }); 
        var phone =rcvdResponse[0];
        return phone;
        }

    });
```

rcvdResponse is a defined array. But it is not returning the output. Can anyone help me to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `return` sentence in the ajax's success callback...

Use [this method instead (creating your own callback function)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5316755/3508426)

Regards.